# Advanced Custom Fields Add Class to Element

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields' flexible content area in a Wordpress theme that I'm developing. One of my `sub_field`s requires a `textarea`.

When I make my `get_sub_field` call from my template it is already wrapped in `<p></p>` tags. How do I go about adding a class to that paragraph?

Example:

```
get_sub_field('textarea');
```

Output:

```
<p>This is my textarea.</p>
```

Desired:

```
<p class="my-class">This is my textarea.</p>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you are calling your Custom Fields with WP editor. Its best to all call it from your template file.

Comment: This link might be use full to you http://blog.andrewmart.in/2014/05/05/speeding-up-wordpress-with-helpers/

Comment: Using jquery? Then try this $("your-textarea-class").parent().addClass("newclass");

Comment: Are you calling your field via WP page in WP admin , or including it directly to your page template file?

Comment: @ShahGhafoori Short answer: I'm calling get_sub_field from my template. Long answer: I've set up a switch statement in my page.php file. Each switch contains an include to the relevant file for that content area type.

Comment: Try this $desc_description=get_sub_field('textarea');
   <p class="temp"><?php echo $desc_description;?></p> 

in your loop

Comment: @ManthanDave That's how I initially had it structured. The result was the following <p class="temp"></p> followed by <p>This is the value from my description field.</p>

Comment: The solution was in the ACF GUI. I needed to change a setting from "Automatically add paragraphs" to "No formatting". Thanks for the discussion, everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your Textarea custom field settings and change "Automatically add paragraphs" to none.

So WP-admin-> Custom Fields -> Field group -> then your field group-> edit textarea-> look for "Controls how new lines are rendered"

Comment: This was the solution that I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't add a class to the p though. this just removes the p entirely, which obviously doesn't answer the OP question. Yes the OP can add p tags in PHP with the class now, but that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a second `false` argument to [`get_sub_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/) to disable reformatting on a case-by-case basis in the template:

```
get_sub_field('textarea', false);
```